# Why google Tag Manager uses IFrame and not the script DOM element?

Tags: javascript, iframe, asynchronous, nonblocking, google-tag-manager

Any reason why Google Tag manager uses hidden IFrame solution? I am referring to this page https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart. Why does it not use the script DOM element approach, like the one described here http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/12/27/coupling-async-scripts/? Thanks.

Comment: Let me take this question back. Taking a closure look at the google tag manager script, it does uses the script DOM element. Actually it uses iframe only when javascript is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the same thing when I first saw it. The IFrame is actually wrapped in a `<noscript>`, meaning it will only be used when JavaScript is disabled.

I added spacing for illustrative purposes:

```
<noscript>
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ABCD"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ABCD');
</script>
```